# onCreate, onCreateOptionsMenu, onResume, what is the order of execution?

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate, onresume, oncreateoptionsmenu

I'm sorry if this question was asked before...
Well anyway as what the title asked, when does onCreateOptionsMenu executed? before or after onResume?

In my app,
when the activity first run/opened the order will be onCreate --> onResume --> onCreateOptionsMenu

But if I change the orientation of the device, it'll automatically called onDestroy and thus the activity will be re-created, in this case the order will be onCreate --> onCreateOptionsMenu --> onResume

I'm so confused now... anybody can give an explanation on this?

Comment: Check this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705927/android-when-is-oncreateoptionsmenu-called-during-activity-lifecycle)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can read about onCreateOptionsMenu [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) :

> This is only called once, the first time the options menu is displayed. To update the menu every time it is displayed, see onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu).

Comment: thanks for the info! I've settled it with invalidateOptionsMenu() which will call onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu).. But still, onCreateOptionsMenu will be called everytime, the activity is destroyed and created again. So everytime I rotate my device, onCreateOptionsMenu() will be executed. and the order of execution is different from if I open the activity for the very first time. This behavior confuses me...

Comment: Maybe inflate for new orientation.