# Testing Menu with Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I am currently learning Robolectric to test for Android and I am having trouble obtaining my application's menu.
Right now, Robolectric's `getOptionsMenu()` is returning null. The code itself works fine but the test always returns null for the options menu.

My code is the following

```
@Test
public void onCreateShouldInflateTheMenu() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setData(Uri.EMPTY);
    DetailActivity dActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(DetailActivity.class, intent).create().get();

    Menu menu = Shadows.shadowOf(dActivity).getOptionsMenu(); // menu is null

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings); // I get a nullPointer exception here
    assertEquals(menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).getTitle().toString(), "Settings");
}
```

Does anyone know why Robolectric is returning null? Did I miss any dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onCreateOptionsMenu` will be called after `oncreate` so to make sure that you can see your menu try

```
Robolectric.buildActivity(DetailActivity.class, intent).create().resume().get();
```

or you can make sure the activity is visible

```
Robolectric.buildActivity(DetailActivity.class, intent).create().visible().get();
```

[From docs](http://robolectric.org/activity-lifecycle/)

What’s This visible() Nonsense?

> `Turns out that in a real Android app, the view hierarchy of an
>   Activity is not attached to the Window until sometime after onCreate()
>   is called. Until this happens, the Activity’s views do not report as
>   visible. This means you can’t click on them` (amongst other unexpected
>   behavior). The Activity’s hierarchy is attached to the Window on a
>   device or emulator after onPostResume() on the Activity. Rather than
>   make assumptions about when the visibility should be updated,
>   Robolectric puts the power in the developer’s hands when writing
>   tests.
>
> So when do you call it? `Whenever you’re interacting with the views
>   inside the Activity. Methods like Robolectric.clickOn() require that
>   the view is visible and properly attached in order to function. You
>   should call visible() after create()`.

[Android: When is onCreateOptionsMenu called during Activity lifecycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705927/android-when-is-oncreateoptionsmenu-called-during-activity-lifecycle)

Comment: What helped me the most was .visible() instead of .resume(). Thank you!