# How to hide\show SearchView from Toolbar?

Tags: android, toolbar, searchview

I have `ToolBar` and I have defined `Searchview` as an item:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"/>
</menu>
```

Then I have `BaseActivity` class where I define `Toolbar`:

```
protected final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, int layoutId)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layoutId);

    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    assert myToolbar != null;

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    return true;
}
```

I have search activity where I show toolbar and I would like to show searchview. The problem is that APP is crashing with **null pointer exception** that it can't find `SearchView` action_search

```
public class SearchActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        SearchView searchview = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.action_search);
        searchview.setVisibility(SearchView.VISIBLE);

    }
}
```

What is correct way to show\hide `SearchView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Kotlin)

Here is a simple way to show/hide searchview:

```
    private lateinit var menuItem: MenuItem
    private var mSearchView: SearchView? = null

    private fun updateSearchUI(visible: Boolean) {
    if (isChecked) {
        menuItem.isVisible = true
    }else{
        menuItem.isVisible = false
    }
    }
```

On first load of Activity if you want to check some preferences and show/hide:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
    menuItem = menu!!.findItem(R.id.shortcut_search)
    mSearchView = menuItem.actionView as SearchView
    updateSearchUI(PreferenceManager.getVisibilityStatus(applicationContext))
    return true
}
```

if you want to toggle searchView show/hide:

```
switch_on_off.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
    updateSearchUI(isChecked)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**In your SearchActivity, use the below code:**

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        menuItem.setVisible(false);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take note that `onCreate` is the first activity life cycle method to be called.  `onCreateOptionsMenu` is triggered during (depending on your Android version) or after `onCreate`. With this in mind, when you `findViewById(R.id.action_search)` inside your `onCreate` method, it will yield a `NULL` object, thus the error.

Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705927/android-when-is-oncreateoptionsmenu-called-during-activity-lifecycle) for other observations by other developers.

> What is correct way to show\hide SearchView?

You don't have to manually show/hide it. In your menu resource, you already have the option `android:showAsAction="never"` included. It [means](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource):

*Never place this item in the app bar. Instead, list the item in the app bar's overflow menu.*

By default, your search view item is already hidden. To show it, you need to click the overflow menu (three dots) on the toolbar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thing is that I want to show SearchView on Toolbar on some Activities and hide on others. That's why I want to hide it by default like android:showAsAction="never" and activate on some Activity.

Comment: first, you need to move your `searchview.setVisibility(SearchView.VISIBLE);` (you will probably not need it) out of `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

First: Change "app:showAsAction" attribute  to "always"

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"/>
</menu>
```

Second: You can not access SearchView directly in onCreate. So remove below code.

```
        SearchView searchview = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.action_search);
        searchview.setVisibility(SearchView.VISIBLE);
```

Third: You can access the SearchView when it is add to toolbar, i.e. when onCreateOptionsMenu is called.

```
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

            MenuItem mSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
            mSearchView = (SearchView) mSearch.getActionView();//Store the reference in global variable of Base activity.
            //Do you customization here, like
            mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
            return true;
    }
```

Fourth: Now you have the reference to SearchView. So you can show/hide search view, like below:

```
       if(mSearchView.isShown()) {
            mSearchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            mSearchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```