# What is the order in which the functions that inherit the Activity are called?

Tags: android

What is the order in which the functions that inherit from Activity are called, in relation to the other functions and in relation to the Activity lifecycle?

functions such as: onCreateOptionsMenu, etc.

I tried a search, but all that came out were results that explain the Activity lifecycle

Comment: Better way to find out Create an `Activity` inherit all methods you want to check and put logs inside each method ..

Comment: Related to and may be the duplicate of -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705927/android-when-is-oncreateoptionsmenu-called-during-activity-lifecycle