# Updating the ActionBar refresh spinner in onResume()

Tags: android, android-actionbar

We're running into a really painful issue with Honeycomb's `ActionBar` here, and I was wondering if anyone else has found a solution. The problem itself is quite simple:

We frequently trigger background tasks in Activity `onCreate` or `onResume`, since most of our screens must display data loaded from a Web service. While these tasks are running, we show the ActionBar's refresh spinner and animate it. The problem is: onCreate and onResume are executed before `onCreateOptionsMenu` is, so at the point where we start the task, the refresh spinner doesn't even exist. Hence, it won't animate.

I don't see any simple way around this. I guess we could keep the information about a task being spawned in onCreate, and as soon as the ActionBar becomes available, update it accordingly. But still, I can't believe a use case as common as this is so difficult to do with ActionBar?

Comment: Any progress on this? Your workaround seems like, well, a workaround.

Comment: I kept using the workaround for lack of a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried using `invalidateOptionsMenu` as outlined in question [How to update a menu item shown in the ActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767570/how-to-update-a-menu-item-shown-in-the-actionbar), but that didn't have any effect.

I ended up tracking pending updates to the action bar using a simple boolean flag. Whenever there are calls to refresh its state, I set the flag, then check and reset it once the bar is created and perform any pending updates. Works great.