# Android Update Menu

Tags: android, android-menu

I need to update my menu. I have a fragment which is created from activity. In that activity, I have an asynchronous method which fetches an object.

It is based on this method that I need to update the menu. At all time, I'm using fragments, I am using onPrepareOptionsMenu method but its not working. This is because when onPrepareOptionsMenu is first called, the object is not yet fetched from the server.

I'm trying to use **invalidateMenuOption** but i'm getting "Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.app.Activity#invalidateOptionsMenu". When I set the API Level to 11, invalidateMenuOption does the job

Is there any turnaround for API Level 8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767570/how-to-update-a-menu-item-shown-in-the-actionbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use Android Support library and then try this. Sure it will work.

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: its ok, its working, supportInvalidateOptionsMenu was the solution, thanks

Comment: did u used support library?