# create a new menu option menu on button click in the same activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am new to android and I recently studied the documentation for option menu in which i have not understood about
        onPrerpareOptionMenu()
.In my application when a button is clicked i want to change option menu for the same activity.

Thanks...

```
  public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    return false;
    menu.clear(); //Clear view of previous menu
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    if( )//condition 
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.view_record, menu);
    else
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.add_record, menu);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: i used ischangedstate but its not showing up.

Comment: try to use onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) instead of onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

Comment: oncreateoptionmenu is called only once then how it will reload the option menu on button click

Comment: check this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767570/how-to-update-a-menu-item-shown-in-the-actionbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this in several of my camera applications to change menu depending on what camera function is enabled via a slide control (although a button also works), i.e for capturing images or videos.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuItem someThing1 = menu.findItem(R.id.someThing1);
    MenuItem someThing2 = menu.findItem(R.id.someThing2);
    MenuItem someThing3 = menu.findItem(R.id.someThing3);
    MenuItem someThing4 = menu.findItem(R.id.someThing4);
    MenuItem someThing5 = menu.findItem(R.id.someThing5);
    MenuItem help = menu.findItem(R.id.help);
    MenuItem about = menu.findItem(R.id.about);
    if (some_condition) { //could be button state or..?
        someThing1.setTitle(R.string.someThing1a);
        someThing2.setTitle(R.string.someThing2a);
        someThing3.setTitle(R.string.someThing3a);
        someThing4.setVisible(false);
        someThing5.setVisible(false);
        help.setVisible(false);
        about.setVisible(false);
    } else {
        someThing1.setTitle(R.string.someThing1b);
        someThing2.setTitle(R.string.someThing2b);
        someThing3.setTitle(R.string.someThing3b);
        someThing4.setVisible(true);
        someThing5.setVisible(true);
        help.setVisible(true);
        about.setVisible(true);
    }
     return true; // this is important to call so that new menu is shown
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. can u plz explain about invalidateoptionmenu() why and how it is used?thanks once again

Comment: Per API: public void invalidateOptionsMenu() Added in API level 11
Declare that the options menu has changed, so should be recreated. The onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) method will be called the next time it needs to be displayed. For <API level 11 use supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() which is the Support library version of invalidateOptionsMenu(). From API: Invalidate the activity's options menu. This will cause relevant presentations of the menu to fully update via calls to onCreateOptionsMenu and onPrepareOptionsMenu the next time the menu is requested. If my answer is a solution, please mark it.